# Beamer headline with sectioning names and numbers

Tags: beamer, sectioning, numbering, headline

I want to create a presentation with Beamer that has a headline similar to that of the theme CambridgeUS, in the sense that it contains the name of the current section (left) and subsection (right), but I want to add the number of the current section and subsection. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could redefine the headline like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{headline}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
    \ifnum\insertsectionnumber>0    
      \insertsectionnumber~
    \fi
    \insertsectionhead
    \hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{headline}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}%
    \hspace*{2ex}%
    \ifnum\insertsubsectionnumber>0 
      \insertsubsectionnumber~
    \fi
    \insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}
\section{title}
\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```